# Jump from horizontal layout to vertical layout responsively without fixed breakpoint

Tags: html, css

There are many ways to achieve this type of horizontal layout with CSS (inline-block, flex, etc):

```
[item 1] [item 2] [item 3] [item 4]
```

If items don't all fit on a single row, these methods typically wrap onto multiple rows, with multiple items per row.

I would like the layout to jump to one item per row for all screen sizes where the items won't fit on a single row:

```
[item 1]
[item 2]
[item 3]
[item 4]
```

Is this achievable with CSS, without:

- javascript
- adding a fixed width break point (which relies on knowing the exact width of the items).

Comment: But surely you (or rather, CSS) will know when they don't fit? You're either using % widths, in which case, they'll always fit, or you're using fixed with, in which case calculating a responsive break-point should be easy?

Comment: There should always be at least an absolute max-width, since you don't want your outer container to be too wide - and if you have SOME width-setting, somewhere, you can usually calculate what you need based on that.

Comment: Items are text based. Not only does the width of text vary slightly from browser to browser, the text is dynamic and changes from page to page.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```css
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }
/*  GRID OF FOUR  */
.span_4_of_4 {
 width: 100%;
}
.span_3_of_4 {
 width: 74.6%;
}
.span_2_of_4 {
 width: 49.2%;
}
.span_1_of_4 {
 width: 23.8%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
 .span_1_of_4, .span_2_of_4, .span_3_of_4, .span_4_of_4 { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="section group">
 <div class="col span_1_of_4">
 1 of 4
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_4">
 1 of 4
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_4">
 1 of 4
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_4">
 1 of 4
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This adds a fixed-width breakpoint, which I specifically mentioned wanting to avoid. The point it adapts should be based on the (unknown) length of content.

Comment: .. you've now managed to ignore *both* the conditions specifically mentioned in my question.